# How to quicken this algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm

The problem statement is:

The player with the highest score is ranked `1` number  on the leaderboard.
Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following ranking number.
For example, four players have the scores 100, 90, 90, 80 and . Those players will have ranks 1, 2, 2 and 3, respectively.

Using this ranking method, need to calculate the ranking of a player based on the scores that he/she makes as it proceeds, player scores provided as an input( 'scores' list). Second, a particular player 'alice's' score is provided , for every game she plays, need to compute where she is placed on the leaderboard.

Suppose there are 6 players on the leaderboard with scores `[100,100,50,40,40,20,10]`. Alice plays her first game, gets a score of 5, she is placed at the bottom of the list with rank 6. Next game she gets 25, now she is placed at rank 4. Next she gets 50, in the next game, this time her rank is 2.

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys
n = int(input().strip())
scores = [int(scores_temp) for scores_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
m = int(input().strip())
alice = [int(alice_temp) for alice_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
# your code goes here
for _ in alice:
    scores.append(_)
    print(list(sorted(set(scores),reverse=True)).index(_)+1)
```

This code works for inputs that are in range 200~500. But if it goes to very high inputs like 10*9, the code is terminating due to timeout. I would like to know how to improvise this code to make it run more quickly

EDIT

```
n = int(input().strip())
scores = sorted(set([int(scores_temp) for scores_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]),reverse=True)
m = int(input().strip())

alice=[int(alice_temp) for alice_temp in input().split(' ')]        
for a in alice:
    rank=1
    for _ in scores:
        if(a<_):
            rank=rank+1
        else:
            #print(rank)
            break
    print(rank)
```

Made this change, however still hitting 'terminating due to timeout', please suggest what needs to be modified

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss lol

Comment: Style nitpick: don't use `_` as a name unless it is a throwaway variable (in your case it is not, since you are using it in your loop).

Comment: if something like this were, in fact, needed to collect data on a large scale, you would need to re-architect it so it doesn't need to process *everything* for *every* update. simply have a daemon program run that keeps all players' current score and just update as per latest score request.  also have it able to add/remove players as needed. what you need is a new program, not an algorithm.

Comment: Anyway, this sounds like a use-case for [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)

Comment: heapq sounds good.  as long as you don't re-fill it each request!

Comment: @user1269942 no, just `heapify` your scores and then `heapq.push` new ones onto the heap!

Comment: Also, don't bother to **strip** the input.  **int()** doesn't care about white space, and re-making strings is going to slow you down somewhat.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  yes, I agree... we speak the same thing.  "push new ones onto the heap"...means the program runs and collects incremental updates instead of parsing the whole thing every time.

Comment: All i need is an algorithm/program in python that performs better than the one in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is an algorithm O(n + m) time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557700/when-is-an-algorithm-on-m-time)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to append Alice's scores to `scores`. First make sure that `scores` is sorted from high to low.

Then for each score of Alice, calculate her rank as follows:

Start with `rank = 1` and iterate over the list of `scores`. Add 1 to `rank` every time the score you're looking at is smaller than the previous one and return the value of `rank` as soon as the score you're looking at equals or is smaller than Alice's score.

### EDIT

This answer assumes that only the highest score of each player is relevant.

Comment: if this is the case, try alice = max([int(alice_temp) for alice_temp in input().strip().split(' ')])

Comment: @user1269942 As I understood the task, the output should be Alice's rank for each of her scores. In that case the max wouldn't help