# Is this bisect function implementation wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that returns rank of a girl named Alice in Python. The type of ranking system used is "dense ranking" system which simply means all the people with the same score get the same rank. I input two lists. the first list(scores) is a list of scores of all players(except Alice of course). The second list(alice) contains the score attained by alice in 'n' tries. Her score increases with each attempt. We have to return a list from the function that contains Alice's rank on the leaderboard after each try.

I tried a lot of approaches to do this. None were both simple and fast at the same time. Finally I found an inbuilt function called bisect_right which is quite suited for my purpose(although I don't think it would be fast enough for my needs, but still I would like to give it a shot), but the output I want is not obtained.Where did I go wrong? Here's my code:

```
def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice):
     res=[]
     unique=list(set(scores))
     unique.reverse()
     length=len(unique)
     for alice_score in alice:
         temp=bisect_right(unique,alice_score)
         res.append(length-temp+1)
     return res
```

If score is [100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60] (notice there are two players scoring 90, they both rank 2nd)
and alice array is [50, 65, 77, 90, 102], the output should be 6,5,4,2,1 (each element is Alice's rank after each play) but the actual output is : 6,5,5,2,1

Why is this happening? Did I do something wrong?

edit: this question is concerned more about how bisect function can be used in this problem and not time complexity of some other more complex approach.

Comment: bisect needs array to be sorted. Your list is sorted in reverse order. and use `bisect`

Comment: As a side note, I think you can do this quite simply by iterating from the end, and updating the rank when appropriate

Comment: when an element (102) is out of the list, the algorithm is different (corner case for insertions)

Comment: @BlackBear Iteration is not a good approach; OP doesn’t mention that N can be as much as 2E5. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard

Comment: @TomZych I meant one iteration, O(N) instead of O(NlogN)

Comment: When you convert from `set`, entries are not in any predictable order. You need to use `sort`.

Comment: @BlackBear Sorry, should have mentioned there can be up to 2E5 queries as well. Binary search is the only way to go.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262411, but that has no accepted answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is an algorithm O(n + m) time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557700/when-is-an-algorithm-on-m-time)

Comment: can anyone explain what's the difference between bisect and bisect-right?

Comment: @TomZych I couldn't explain myself properly in English, here's how to do it without binary search: https://pastebin.com/LGERedTp

Comment: I think the code i submitted in my answer is the simplest way to do it. Definitely the simplest solution I have encountered. It leaves it all to the computer to figure out most of the logic so you can move on with your life in peace.

Comment: @BlackBear But isn’t that O(N) for each query? M and N can both be up to 2E5. It would time out.

Comment: @TomZych no, it's O(N+M) or something linear like that, _in total_. Notice that we don't reset `alice_rank` every time, but we start from the previous one and only decrease. It is very fast, try to submit it :p

Comment: @BlackBear Oh! You’re right. Very nice algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I had been sorting the array wrong. I forgot that "reverse" sorts the array in reverse order.

Here's the final code that works:

```
res=[]
unique=list(set(scores))
unique.sort()     
length=len(unique)
for alice_score in alice:
    temp=bisect-right(unique,alice_score)    #but bisect works too, i don't know why
    res.append(length-temp+1)
return res
```